# Slider horizontal thumbnavigator size and number of images

Tags: javascript, html, css, jssor

I have two question regarding the thumbnavigator:

1-  How can I make the size of the thumbnavigator bigger without adding more columns to it.

2- Is there anyway to increase the space between each image inside the thumbnavigator?

cheers,

es

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re 1:
Given a thumbnail navigator skin, you can modify css code to change size of thulmbnail.

Re 2:
Please specify `$SpacingX` or `$SpacingY` option.

Btw, it's very easy to do this job with Jssor Slider Maker.